# SQL Server filter rows which are being selected in other transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

i have a couple of jobs Update from select queries e.g

```
UPDATE TABLE_X
SET "stopFlag" = 1
OUTPUT 
    INSERTED."RowID" AS "rowID"
WHERE "RowID" IN (
    SELECT TOP 50
        "RowID"
    FROM
        TABLE_X
    WHERE
        stopFlag=0
)
```

Currently i was thinking that the update cannot conflict with another update but as i see the logs of my database tables it seems that 2 different jobs executed for a single row resulting in messed up data. My question is. Is this a proper way to filter the rows from being selected. If it is then what am i missing?

Comment: This has a lot do with concurrency levels, which are confusing, but may I suggest you switch in read committed isolation and put this in a transaction?

Comment: isnt this the default transaction level? also will this lead to one transaction waiting for the other because that was what i was trying to bypass. i wanted 2 sql statements to run side by side.

Answer (score 1):

A transaction is *not* necessary here, as every statement runs in an auto-commit transaction anyway.

You could up the isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE`, which may be more consistent, at the cost of more blocking. You could also add an `UPDLOCK` hint to the inner reference of `Table_X`.

But I think the best thing to do here will actually improve performance also: don't self-join the table, just update the derived table directly

```sql
UPDATE x
SET stopFlag = 1
OUTPUT 
    inserted.RowID AS rowID
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 50
        RowID,
        stopFlag
    FROM
        TABLE_X
    WHERE
        stopFlag = 0
) x;
```

An `UPDLOCK` is automatically taken on any rows read from the table reference which is being updated, so that is not necessary.

Comment: I ended up using parts from your answer and parts from David Browne. Thank you both so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the statements to run concurrently, but mark and return disjoint rows, use READPAST.  You can even introduce ordering guarantees, eg:

```
UPDATE TABLE_X
SET "stopFlag" = 1
OUTPUT 
    INSERTED."RowID" AS "rowID"
WHERE "RowID" IN (
    SELECT TOP 50
        "RowID"
    FROM
        TABLE_X with (rowlock, updlock, readpast)
    WHERE
        stopFlag=0
    ORDER BY "RowID"
)
```

See generally [Using tables as Queues](https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/).

Comment: Thanks. i will look into it. One question regarding my code. If i put a case when inside the update set wont that do the trick as sort of a second check so i ensure that the data is not tampered with and avoid using locks and other stuff?

Comment: No, you need locks to make this work.

Comment: I ended up using parts from  your answer and parts from Charlieface. Thank you both so much.